# Grouping an array of similar words

Tags: php

I have an array with a bunch of words. E.g:

```
array( developer,develop,development,design,designer,designing )
```

I want to be able to group these words together with their similar words so I'd get something like this:

```
array(
   array( develop, developer, development ),
   array( design, designer, designing ),
);
```

What would be the best way to do this in PHP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it easily using [`metaphone()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.metaphone.php):

```
$result = array();
foreach ($array as $word) {
    $result[metaphone($word, 2)][] = $word;
}
```

`print_r($result);` will show:

```
Array
(
    [TF] => Array
        (
            [0] => developer
            [1] => develop
            [2] => development
        )

    [TS] => Array
        (
            [0] => design
            [1] => designer
            [2] => designing
        )
)
```

Comment: The PHP API (if you can call it that) keeps amazing me. The amount of useful "stuff" that's build into the language is just amazing.

Comment: Yes, there is a function for almost everything. Actually it is amazing :)

Answer (score 4):

A way is comming to my mind

```
$array = array( 'developer','develop','development','design','designer','designing' );

function matchWords(array $in,$pad='4')
{
    $ret = array();
    foreach ($in as $v) {
        $sub = substr($v, 0, $pad);
        if (!isset($ret[$sub])) {
            $ret[$sub] = array();
        }
        $ret[$sub][] = $v;
    }

    return array_values($ret);
}

print_r(matchWords($array,4));

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => developer
            [1] => develop
            [2] => development
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => design
            [1] => designer
            [2] => designing
        )
)
```

This matches the `$pad` first letters of your array values and create a key on it.

Comment: I had a hard time deciding to accept your answer or that of jackflash. In the end I actually used the one jackflash provided so I feel I need to tick that as the correct answer. However, if I was able to accept two answers I would. I praise you for your quick response to my question! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to extract the stem of each word using a technique such as "Porter Stemming" to identify the similar words, then build your array based on those stems. You can find a PHP implementation of a Porter Stemmer [here](http://www.chuggnutt.com/stemmer)

Comment: I thought about stemming before asking the question but it might have been to slow in performance (I know, premature optimization is the root of all evil and all that). Thanks anyway!